# Can I stop my program from printing repetitive information

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist, system.out

I am trying to fix up my project to find and tell me which students are trying to register with another name so I programmed my code to search my arraylist and find those with same id number as follows, but is it possible to change or add something so that it does not print out the same information twice

Example test case

```
Student ID 103 is repeating the class as names Mark Wall and Stacy Gwee
Student ID 103 is repeating the class as names Stacy Gwee and Mark Wall



for(int n = 0; n<studentList.size(); n++)
         {
         for(int m = 0; m<studentList.size(); m++)
            {
            if(studentList.get(n).getId().equals(studentList.get(m).getId()) && !studentList.get(n).getName().equals(studentList.get(m).getName()))
               {
               System.out.println("Student ID " + studentList.get(n).getId() + " is repeating the class as names " + studentList.get(n).getName() + " and " + studentList.get(m).getName());
               }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Shorten the 2nd loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it simply change the second for loop:

```
for(int m = 0; m < n; m++)
```

Comment: this works perfectly thank you! but if you dont mind me asking, how exactly does this work, since both are at 0 shouldnt the program not run this since its 0 !< 0

Comment: The first iteration will basically prevent you from checking the first entry against itself, since ID100 John would definitely equal ID100 John. Then n grows after that and starts follow-checking everything prior to it.

Answer (score 4):

Simple ways:

```
for(int m = 0 ; m < n ; m++)
```

Or

```
for(int m = n + 1 ; m < studentList.size() ; m++)
```

Comment: To my personal taste I like [this notation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25942284/2055998) better.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the proper way to do it:

1. Create a Map
2. Add your matches to the map
3. Check the map if the ID has already been used before checking your List

You need some way to flag your duplicates. You can create a list or an array to mark these duplicates. You then would check the ID to make sure that it hasn't been called before.

Comment: I think OP's class has not gone to maps yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine your array as a grid n spaces wide and m spaces high, you are looking at each grid square.

If you draw a diagonal line across your grid you actually only need to look at those above the line (or below).

Therefore you inner loop could start, not at zero, but at the value of n.

Comment: The diagonal itself needs to be excluded. So it's `n+1`.